# Getting InvalidSelectorException while finding the element in selenium using "eq" comparison operator

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate an element `<div>` in selenium based on its child element.

Sample HTML code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="class1">Foo</div>
    <span>Val1</span>
    <h1>Heading1</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[h1 = 'Heading1']")    //Statement1
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[h1 eq 'Heading1']")    //Statement2
```

Now, in the selenium code, the Statement1 works fine, but the Statement2 is throwing an exception: `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given xpath expression is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`

Any idea why this exception is thrown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because according to [XPath specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-EqualityExpr) the equality expression requires `=` but not `eq`. This is why your second statement cannot be parsed.

Comment: But as per Xpath doc, it has 2 types of comparison operators: value comparison and general comparison.

Comment: Can you add a reference to such statement?

Comment: Please check [https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-comparisons](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-comparisons)

Comment: This is the specification of xpath version 3. Browsers have native support of version 1 unfortunately, so that when you use xpath selectors you have to take that into account.

Comment: Can I please get the link which mentions which browsers support which xpath version ?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(XML)#Query_technologies